# How to show a program in text view..?

Tags: android, textview

I want to show a simple java program in my app

when i put the below code in my textview it simply shows it like a paragraph.
How to show a program in my textview like the format given below

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello, World!");
   }
 }
```

Help me :-) please

Comment: I suggest you start reading the android documentation first.

Comment: Please read first Android Tutorials. Go http://developer.android.com

Answer (score 1):

I dont have any idea how you are trying but refer my answer i think you will get some idea

```
String firststring = "public class Main {";
   String secondstring = "public static void main(String[] args) {";
   String thirdstring = "System.out.println("Hello, World!");";
   textview.setText(Html.fromHtml(firststring + "<br>" + secondstring+"<br>"+thirdstring));//Your textview
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally got the answer.

Place texts which you want to look like a program in the Syntax highlighter save it as html and put it on assets folder load the url in webview!

That's what I found on matter:

[Syntax Highlighter Link](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/)